# How to draw an octagon in TikZ with some text inside it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I am new to  tikz. I need to use an octagon in my work. Somehow i managed to draw a single pentagon?

How to draw the octagon, set the text inside with the arrows? Is there exist any command for drawing octagon?

Here is what we have tried so far.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6]
\draw[ultra thick,color=black,fill=gray!20,text = black] (0,1)--(-0.9510565163,0.309017)--(-0.58778525229,-0.809017)--(0.58778525229,0.809017)--(0.9510565163,0.309017)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use the `shapes.geometric` library with the `regular polygon` node shape and `regular polygon sides=8`.

Comment: if you don't want a regular octogon, you can name the node and use the corners, like (name.north east).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[octagon/.style=
  {shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, draw, minimum width=.8in}]
  \node[octagon] (India) {India};
  \node[octagon, below left=of India] (Italy) {Italy};
  \node[octagon, below right=of India] (Sweden) {Sweden};
  \draw[->] (Italy) -- node [left] {A} (India);
  \draw[->] (Sweden) -- node [right] {BC} (India);
    \draw[->] (Sweden) -- node [above] {CDE} (Italy);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Suppose that, if i am writing a phrase inside the octagon, then it's size expands. How to set a unique size for all the octagons of the figure.

Comment: the key `minimal width` will give you the minimal width of the node.  I used it in my example, otherwise Sweden would be larger than India

Comment: The current syntax would load `shapes.geometric` rather than the deprecated `shapes`. At least, as I understand it.

Comment: Page 693: 'Note that the library shapes is provided for compatibility
only. Please include sublibraries like `shapes.geometric` or `shapes.misc` directly.' The same is true for all of these deprecated libraries e.g. `arrows` and so on.

Comment: You are right of course :)